# Как правильно подключить scss в webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, scss

Появилась потребность поставить Sass в проект на React и вот проблема:
когда стартует проект выдаёт ошибку:

```
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
```

При этом у меня всё установлено:

```
"node-sass": "^4.8.3", "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
```

В конфиге прописал следующее:

```
{test: /\.scss$/,include: paths.appSrc,loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']}
```

В чём может быть ошибка, вообще не понимаю. Очень надеюсь на вас!

Comment: а можно увидеть полный webpack.config, а так же какая версия webpack

Comment: хотя ругается на версию node-sass

Answer (score 1):

Это проблема в npm или в кэшированной версии node-sass. Для того чтобы наверняка решить проблему нужно прописать `npm install npm -g`, затем `npm rebuild node-sass` или (если не помогло):

1. Удалить node-sass из node_modules.
2. Удалить packages-lock.json.
3. Удалить node-sass из глобального npm-кэша (Для Windows это %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache)
4. Обновить версию npm до последней.
5. Заново загрузить пакет node-sass.

Answer (score 0):

можно посмотреть какие пакеты нуждаются в обновлении

1. npm outdated проверяет какие пакеты имеют обновления, потом желательно вручную их обновлять (обновив все можно потерять совместимость с проектом)
2. в вашем случае npm update --save node-sass команда сама установит вам последнюю стабильную версию и перепишет ее в package.json